# Incorrect Number format

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, tooltip

I am currently building a weather application. Below is the code I am using to render the Google chart.

```
function drawLineGraph() {
    var options = {
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: variable
        },
        //backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9',
        interpolateNulls: false

    };
    var data = [];
    var title = [];
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'TimeLine');
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '##.##'+units[0]});
        for (var i = 0; i < n_variables; i++) {
        data.addColumn('number', variables[i] + ' ' + agg_levels[i])
    }
    data.addRows(y)
    for (var i = 0; i < n_variables; i++) {
    formatter.format(data, i+1)    }
    
    
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I am facing a problem with respect to the formatting of data. As seen in the below image, even though I have added the decimal separator after the second value, I am getting it displayed only after the fourth. I want the value to be shown as 71.33%

[image: weather1]

I also noticed that if I replace the decimal sign by comma, things become good. I am currently based in Germany where actually decimal is used instead of comma. So is this a region issue ? Any way I can hard-code into my javascript  to set defualt region ?
[image: weather2]

Comment: Have your tried the `decimalSymbol` and `groupingSymbol` options of `Numerformat` as described in the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat)

Answer (score 0):

there are various options you can try using the formatter, as noted in the comment.

but you can control the formatted value by loading the data using object notation.

when adding your data using `addRows`, for each cell value, you can object notation.

where `v:` is the value, and `f:` is the formatted value.

```
{v: 71.33, f: '71,33%'}

data.addRows([
  ['8:00 PM', {v: 71.33, f: '71,33%'}]
]);
```

you can also load specific locales when loading google charts,
which will probably resolve your issue without any of the above options.
see --> [load with locale](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale)